# Getting MapReduce results on RIAK (using the Java client)

Tags: java, mapreduce, riak

I am storing Person POJOs (4 string fields - id, name, lastUpdate, Data) on RIAK, then trying to fetch these objects with MapReduce.

I am doing it very similar to Basho documentation:

```
    BucketMapReduce m = riakClient.mapReduce("person");
    m.addMapPhase(new NamedJSFunction("Riak.mapByFields"), true);
    MapReduceResult result = m.execute();
    Collection<Person> tmp = result.getResult(Person.class);
```

the Person's String constructor is invoked:

```
public Person(String str){}
```

(I must have this constructor, otherwise I get an exception for it is missing)
In there I get the object as a String - the Object's fields in one string with a strange delimiter.

why am I not getting the object automatically converted to my POJO? do I really need to go over the string and deserialize it? am i doing something wrong?s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JS function you're using doesn't do what you think it does :) It selects objects based on a field with a specific value you have to supply as an argument to the phase.

I think what you're looking for is `mapValuesJson` which will do what you seem to be wanting to do.

Also, you don't need a constructor at all in your POJO.

The code below should point you in the right direction (obviously this is super-simple with all public fields in the POJO and no annotations):

```
public class App {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, RiakException
    {
        IRiakClient client = RiakFactory.httpClient();
        Bucket b = client.fetchBucket("test_mr").execute();

        b.store("myobject", new Person()).execute();
        IRiakObject o = b.fetch("myobject").execute();
        System.out.println(o.getValueAsString());


        BucketMapReduce m = client.mapReduce("test_mr");
        m.addMapPhase(new NamedJSFunction("Riak.mapValuesJson"), true);
        MapReduceResult result = m.execute();
        System.out.println(result.getResultRaw());
        Collection<Person> tmp = result.getResult(Person.class);

        for (Person p : tmp)
        {
            System.out.println(p.data);
        }


        client.shutdown();
    }
}

class Person 
{
    public String id = "12345";
    public String name = "my name";
    public String lastUpdate = "some time";
    public String data = "some data";


}
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your response. actually I have tried the JS functions you mention, but with that I don't even pass the execute stage. I get an IOException:{"phase":0,"error":"[{<<\"lineno\">>,477},{<<\"message\">>,<<\"JSON.parse\">>},{<<\"source\">>,<<\"unknown\">>}]","input":"{ok,{r_object,<<\"new\">>,<<\"2\">>,[{r_content,{dict,7....                                       perhaps the annotations you mentioned are what i am missing?

Comment: It sounds like whatever you have stored in riak isn't valid JSON; e.g. the `JSON.parse` error (or at the very least, at least one item you have stored isn't valid). The above code is a fully working example- annotations are not required; they're used if you want to specify indexes, links, etc when reading/writing objects.

Comment: Hey Brian, thanks a lot! I was running your example and was getting my original exception: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.att.cso.omss.data.riak.controllers.RiakBaseController$Personx]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
then I created a new clean project with your code - and it worked! apparently, some older dependencies in my POM were pointing to other json version which was overriding the one RIAK needs. thanks!

Comment: @user1510151 - Glad I could help. Please consider upvoting the answer and accepting it. Also, you can get ahold of us directly on riak-users mailing list, http://lists.basho.com/mailman/listinfo/riak-users_lists.basho.com - all our engineers monitor and reply to the list.

Comment: btw - when I am storing an object withConvertor(KRYO), the mapreduce doesn't work --> I get the de-serialization exception. is there a way to make it work? because without the withConvertor storing the linkWalking is problematic...