# Riak-Java cannot deserialize domain objects from MapReduce query in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, riak, domain-object

Performing a MapReduce query on a simple bucket. For some reason, I am getting an exception from Jackson:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of com.threetierlogic.AccountService.models.User out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@39494ff0; line: 1, column: 2]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:219)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.mappingException(StdDeserializationContext.java:212)
        ... 179 more
```

Here's the MapReduce Query I am performing:

```
DB.client.mapReduce(bucketName)
    .addReducePhase(NamedErlangFunction.REDUCE_IDENTITY)
    .execute().getResult(classOf[User])
```

Now if I call the JSON using `getResultRaw()` it returns a string of JSON that contains no values, only keys:

```
[["accounts-user","8f0bb6e41592690d701225e263807a5e"],["accounts-user","2687cf9444013c45ba2637e9f6d3d3ad"],["accounts-user","3507e2e1f3d2818fdd276214d594c8e"],["accounts-user","fd186b0293ab7eb737f8b66e353fe4a6"],["accounts-user","bf6ce6bca0f642abfe74f2e2281e676c"],["accounts-user","b58d356551a8df6d3bbaf65e577f4b12"],["accounts-user","8126d599d259fd43f701c90787096049"],["accounts-user","33b9ae3befb23b7030b609158bb762d"],["accounts-user","770a897d5ce8c8e118ae121fc01f4c80"],["accounts-user","edae605390c35256b5df055f5574734d"],["accounts-user","ef19ad34a2be4ab8de111d1590a8768b"],["accounts-user","89a9f29ac937595038d37169f9ba7c8"],["accounts-user","85be26f43f7bb74eefa7683dcc74c555"]]
```

So what am I overlooking here? Do I need to invoke some sort of domain converter or is the problem in the MapReduce query itself?

### Edit

If it helps, here's how I store `IRiakObjects` in Riak:

```
def store(o: User) = bucket.store(o).withConverter(new UserConverter(bucketName)).execute()
```

Comment: `NamedErlangFunction.REDUCE_IDENTITY` returns a list of bucket/key pairs (as you can see, this is converted to a JSON array that contains multiple arrays, each with a bucket and key). I suspect you're trying to get something else.

Comment: This may be a conceptual misunderstanding (still learning). However, does `NamedJSFunction("Riak.mapValuesJson")` return object values? If so, then I am still getting errors. Any relevant doc links to share?

Comment: I checked out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543447/getting-mapreduce-results-on-riak-using-the-java-client?rq=1 I followed the steps in the Riak-java Github to create a DomainConverter. I am guessing the two methodologies are incompatible?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do? Just get all the objects from a bucket?

Comment: That's correct. Still wrapping my head around MapReduce, but it appears that serializing domain objects using kryo seems to necessitate different methods of pulling objects?

Comment: Ok nearly there. resorting back to POJO, i am simply stuck on one final issue. going to store a POJO creates the issue `com.basho.riak.client.convert.ConversionException: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found`. a similar issue on the mailing list looks unanswered. i'll investigate further. I suspect this may be an issue with Scala `case class` again ;)

Comment: So yeah ... posting answer. The problem is you can't go straight to your POJO with mapreduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem as noted in the comments is that `REDUCE_IDENTITY` returns a list of bucket/key pairs which isn't what you want. Second problem is ... you can't go straight to your POJO from mapreduce if you're storing something other than JSON. Third (sorta) problem is ... Riak mapreduce is really not made for binary values.

The following uses the `KryoPersonConverter` and `Person` class from the [example in the cookbook](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/wiki/Using-a-custom-Converter) that demonstrates how to use Kryo in a custom converter.

I'm going to break to code sample up and inline my comments:

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws RiakException
    {
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();

        Person p = new Person("Bob","111 Elm Street","555-1212");
        personList.add(p);
        p = new Person("Jenny","122 Spruce Lane","867-5309");
        personList.add(p);
        p = new Person("Steve","333 Oak place","555-1111");
        personList.add(p);


        IRiakClient client = RiakFactory.pbcClient();
        Bucket b = client.fetchBucket("people").execute();
        KryoPersonConverter converter = new KryoPersonConverter("people");

        for (Person p2 : personList)
        {
            b.store(p2).withConverter(converter).execute();
        }

        p = new Person();
        p.setName("Jenny");
        p = b.fetch(p).withConverter(converter).execute();
        assert(p.getPhone().equals("867-5309")); // I got your number
```

Everything up to now? A-OK! We've stored a POJO in Riak after having used Kryo to serialize it, and retrieved it.

```
        MapReduceResult result = client.mapReduce("people")
                                       .addMapPhase(NamedErlangFunction.MAP_OBJECT_VALUE)
                                       .execute();

        System.out.println(result.getResultRaw());
```

And here we see the problem, as the output of that `println()` is:

```
["\u0001\u0001\u000e111 Elm Street\u0001\u0003Bob\u0001\b555-1212","\u0001\u0001\r333 Oak place\u0001\u0005Steve\u0001\b555-1111","\u0001\u0001\u000f122 Spruce Lane\u0001\u0005Jenny\u0001\b867-5309"]
```

Unfortunately, mapreduce in Riak is really meant to be used with JSON data (or just plain strings) when talking about stored data. We have a JSON array containing JSON strings of the bytes we stored.

To work with that, you'd have to get the `String`s as a `Collection`, then convert the bytes using Kryo.

```
        Collection<String> objects = result.getResult(String.class);


        Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
        kryo.register(Person.class);
        ObjectBuffer buffer = new ObjectBuffer(kryo);

        for (String s : objects)
        {
            Person p3 = buffer.readObject(s.getBytes(), Person.class);
            System.out.println(p3.getName() + " " + p3.getPhone());
        }

        client.shutdown();     
    }
}
```

And you'd get the output:

> Bob 555-1212
> Steve 555-1111
>  Jenny 867-5309

Comment: Well that about sums it up. A good reason to resort back to POJO and JSON ;) Wish I realized this from the start. However, I definitely learned a lot from your answer and I bet this comes in handy down the road. On another note, really appreciate your awesome support!

Comment: It's *sorta* useful .. if your mapreduce jobs are only concerned about *keys* then this is not a problem (subsets of keys come to mind). The only real issue is that the `MapReduceResult` doesn't have any way to pass your converter in which is just a shortcoming of the client design. Something like `Collection<Person> c = result.getResult(Person.class, converter)` would be a lot cleaner ... but the existing `Converter<T>`  wouldn't work because it's meant to work with `IRiakObject` (and vector clocks) :(